# How to add a string(s) after a specific string is read?

Tags: perl, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I want to write a script to be executed in the terminal.

I'm editing xml files and I want to add a string or strings after the head of the xml column is detected..

Here is a sample xml

```
bunch of line
more unimportant lines
and they can very in number
<States>
<item1> something something </item1>

<item2> something something </item1>

<item3> something something </item1>
</states>
```

Now I want to add an item 4. However, I want it to be inserted before item1.

Idealy, the file would when look like:

```
bunch of line
more unimportant lines
and they can very in number
and even some lines were added here
and here
and here
<States>
<item4> something something </item1>
<item1> something something </item1>

<item2> something something </item1>

<item3> something something </item1>
</states>
```

Note that there was other stuff added to the top that is irrelevent to the code. These are comments that are going to be going in.

I am open to doing this in perl, but shell would be even better.

Comment: `<item2> ... </item1>` is that correct...? Doesn't look like valid xml.

Comment: I recommend an XML parser, most of which should be able to inject a new element inside some scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this assuming your heading `States` is fixed

```
$ tlines=`wc -l your_file | cut -f1  -d ' '`
$ lno=`grep -n "<States>"  your_file | cut -f1 -d ':'`
$ head -${lno} your_file > your_file.tmp
$ cat file_to_insert >> your_file.tmp
$ tail -`expr ${tlines} - ${lno}` your_file >> your_file.tmp
```

After this `your_file.tmp` will have inserted lines from `file_to_insert`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/<States>/a\
<item4> something something </item4>
' input-file
```